# Why am I not able to fetch email with the following code (the second console statement not giving me anything)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the email printed in the console that is entered in a form. My code seems right, it is compiling fine but it is not fetching the email. I want to use nodemailer to send emails upon registration, but I'm not able to get the data from frontend to backend. What looks wrong with the code?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'  
import './LoginSignUp.css'  
import email_icon from '../Assets/email_icon.png'  
import person_icon from '../Assets/person_icon.png'  
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'  
import Validation from './SignUpValidation';  
import axios from 'axios'  

export const SignUp = () => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

  const handleInput = (event) => {  
    setValues(prev => ({ ...prev, [event.target.name]: [event.target.value] }))  
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {  
    event.preventDefault();  
    setErrors(Validation(values));  
    if (errors.name === "" && errors.email === "" && errors.password === "") {  
      axios.post('http://localhost:8081/signup', values)  
        .then(res => {  
          navigate('/');  
        }  
        )  
        .catch(err => console.log(err));  
    }  
  }   

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");  
  console.log(email);  

  const sendEmail = async (e) => {  
    e.preventDefault();  

    const res = await fetch("/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email
      })
    });
    //I'm not getting anything printed after clicking the Sign Up button
    console.log(res)
  }

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className="header">
        <div className="text">Sign Up</div>
        <div className="underline"></div>
      </div>
      //input fields
      <form className="inputs" action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="input">
            <img src={person_icon} alt="" style={{ width: '20px', height: '20px' }} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name='name' onChange={handleInput} />
            {errors.name && <span className='text-danger'>{errors.name}</span>}
          </div>

          <div className="input">
            <img src={email_icon} alt="" style={{ width: '20px', height: '20px' }} />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name='email' value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
          </div>
        </div>
        //submit button
        <div className="submit-container">
          <button type='submit' className="submit-button" onClick={sendEmail}>Sign Up</button>
          <Link to="/" className="submit-button">Login</Link>
        </div>

      </form>


    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `e.preventDefault()` and `event.preventDefault()` in your event handlers, so I think one of your functions (`handleSubmit` or `sendEmail`) is not running at all. You can verify that by adding a console log in the beginning of each of those functions.

Also, it is possible that your backend is not responding so your `axios.post` or `fetch` call is stuck forever. You can verify that by looking at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: I just just checked that `sendEmail()` function is running but the `handleSubmit()` is not. What could be the reason and what can I do to handle that?

Comment: This is my backend code:`require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = require("./routes/router");
const cors = require("cors")
const port = 8006;


// middle ware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(router)


app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`server start at port no :${port}`)
})`

Comment: This is not an issue with your backend then, it's an issue with the front-end. In `sendEmail` you're calling `e.preventDefault()` which (as the name suggests) prevents the default behavior of this button, which is submitting the form, which is calling `handleSubmit`. You should remove `e.preventDefault()` from `sendEmail` and then `handleSubmit` will work.

Comment: Also, those two functions will be run in exactly the same moment, so I don't really understand why you defined both of them. You can use either one or the other, there's no reason to have two. I would recommend choosing `onSubmit` on the `form` element because it is will be also triggered when the form submitted in a different way than clicking the button.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it and marking it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, that helped now both of those functions are running, however I'm still not sure if my backend is getting the data from the frontend. I'm getting this error in my backend now: server start at port no :8006
{}
ErrorError: No recipients defined

Comment: Here is my router.js code:    `const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
// send mail
router.post("/signup",  (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    

    try {

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: "gmail",
            auth: {
                user: process.env.EMAIL,
                pass: process.env.PASSWORD
            }
        });`

Comment: `const mailOptions = {
            from: process.env.EMAIL,
            to: {email},
            subject: "Sending Email With React And Nodejs",
            html: '<h1>Congratulation</h1> <h1> You successfully sent Email </h2>'
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error" + error)
            } else {
                console.log("Email sent:" + info.response);
                res.status(201).json({status:201,info})
            }
        })

    }`

Comment: `catch (error) {
        console.log("Error" + error);
        res.status(401).json({status:401,error})
    }
});
module.exports = router;`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know much about express! The only thing that seems weird to me is that you're passing the receipient in `mailOptions` (`to` field) as an object (`{email}`) and not just a string. You check check that or you can post another question regarding that. Also, if my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it and marking it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I don't know what exactly worked out but I managed to send an emails from my website.